# How to surpress error message/comment in drop down box

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a drop-down list like this:

```
//Create a drop-down with all positions
function doPopulatePositionDropdown() {
  var positionMD = getPositionMD();
  var positions=[]; var j = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<positionMD.length;i++){  

    if(positionMD[i][1] != ''){
      positions[j] = positionMD[i][1]; 
      j++;
    };
  };

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(positions, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .setHelpText('You can only choose a free which is not already taken')
                           .build();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('ChoosePosition');
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
};
```

The use-case is that a coach is supposed to select a player for each positions.

In order to ensure that each playing position can only be occupied by one player positionMD only contains these positions which have not already been assigned to a player (i.e positionMD = the free positions).

When the coach assigns a player to a position, the drop down list of selectable (=free positions) is reduced in that doPopulatePositionDropdown() is called by onEdit.

Thus, each time the coach assigns a position to a player the drop down list of free positions shrinks, so the coach can easily see which positions are still unassigned (and he does not risk to assign the same position twice).

It all works exactly as expected :-)

The only problem is that those cells where a position has been selected now appear with a small comment-style red triangle denoting an error. The error is obviously that the value in the cell is not valid (which is correct since it is not part of the set of entries in positonsMD once it has been selected).

From the point of view of the application logic this is not an error in this case and I want to get surpress it along with the hoover over text.

Is there a away of surpressing this error message???

Another simplistic way of describing this issue is that if you create a data validation rule over a range already containing values and those values are not valid according to the validation rule. How do you surpress the error for those already existing values?

Please note: it is purely a question of usability since the coach is confused by the message saying that the position he has selected from the drop-down list is invalid.

Also: if you think the the answer is 'you could also disable the data validation on a range by calling setDataValidation(rule) to allow any input, then set the data validation back to the old one after you've inserted the data you need' then you are misunderstading what the problem is.

Here a reproducable example:

```
function onEdit() {
  doPopulatePositionDropdown();
};

function doPopulatePositionDropdown() {
  var pos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,''].filter(e => e !== '')
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet0!A1:A2');
 
  var takenRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
                       .getRange('Sheet0!A1:A2')
                       .getValues()
                       .flat().filter(function(value) {
    return ( value != '')
  });
  takenSet = new Set(takenRange);
  pos = pos.filter(dataRow =>!takenSet.has(dataRow));

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(pos, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .setHelpText('You can only choose a free which is not already taken')
                           .build();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```

Thanx to Cooper!

Comment: @Cooper thanx. I modified your example to illustrate exactly what the issue is. Once the user selects one of the values in the original pos, he cannot select it again (which is good!), but there is an error showing in the cell (which I would like to surpress).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

Warning of data validation cannot be removed. Although there is a "hacky" way of hiding it.

#### Workaround:

Set the background color of the range to the same color of the warning icon which is `#ff5621` after setting the data validation rule.

```
// set rule
range.setDataValidation(rule);
// hide warning icon by setting background of range to the same color
range.setBackground("#ff5621");
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

Warning will still pop out when choosing new value, but at least hidden when not being used. Though you have to be using background color on the range.

Comment: thanx, but it seems as if I am doing a horrible job at explaining myself. I am sorry for this. Please note: my modification of Cooper's answer is EXACTLY the right solution, EXCEPT the warning/error message which I want to get rid of. Your suggestion does the opposite in that it adds values to the list, but I want a SHRINKING list of valid values. The use-case is that the coach a) does not assign the same position twice b) he sees which positions remain to assign. Thus, is there a way to surpress the default warning/error (red triangle in cell) which doesn't follow the data validation?

Comment: @mortpiedra, see modified solution above. It only hides the warning icon when dropdown not in used. But you need to set the range's background color to the same color of the warning icon. Definitely not a fix, but is the only thing to hide the warning icon.

Comment: HA HA I like your creativity :-). Thanx.

Comment: @mortpiedra, yeah, i just asked some colleague and he gave me the idea. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
function doPopulatePositionDropdown() {
  var pos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,''].filter(e => e !== '')
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
                           .requireValueInList(pos, true)
                           .setAllowInvalid(false)
                           .setHelpText('You can only choose a free which is not already taken')
                           .build();
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Sheet0!A1');
  range.setDataValidation(rule);  
}
```